# ehcache help needed

Tags: ehcache

Hello i am trying to setup Ehcache on my local system , There is only java based caching ,i am performing . I got the exception when i just ran the main method " 10:16:32,637 INFO  [main] Main  - javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory=null

10:16:32,684 FATAL [main] Main  - No embedded stylesheet instruction for file: file:/C:/workspaces/Ehacache/EhcacheTest/src/config/ehcache.xml
org.eclipse.wst.xsl.jaxp.debug.invoker.TransformationException: No embedded stylesheet instruction for file: file:/C:/workspaces/Ehacache/EhcacheTest/src/config/ehcache.xml
    at org.eclipse.wst.xsl.jaxp.debug.invoker.internal.JAXPSAXProcessorInvoker.transform(JAXPSAXProcessorInvoker.java:225)
    at org.eclipse.wst.xsl.jaxp.debug.invoker.internal.JAXPSAXProcessorInvoker.transform(JAXPSAXProcessorInvoker.java:186)
    at org.eclipse.wst.xsl.jaxp.debug.invoker.internal.Main.main(Main.java:73)
Caused by: org.eclipse.wst.xsl.jaxp.debug.invoker.TransformationException: No embedded stylesheet instruction for file: "

In my Code i have put only this in the main method

```
CacheManager cm = new CacheManager("src/config/ehcache.xml");
    String[] test = cm.getCacheNames();
    System.out.println(test.length);
```

and also in my src/config/ i have put only ehcache.xml. I didnot put ehcache.xsd, Do i need to mention that also

Answer (score 1):

My take is that you are not running your Java class' main method, but Eclipse is trying to execute your ehcache.xml file. You need to make sure you run the correct target.